# Is there a positive radical Aurous, Au (x+)?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

Is there a positive radical Aurous, $\ce{{Au}^{x+}}$? If yes what is the value of x?

We have Auric as $\ce{{Au}^{3+}}$.

Answer (score 4):

*Aurous* would appear to denote Gold(I), that is, $x=+1$, as [detailed on this site](http://gold.atomistry.com/aurous_chloride.html), which gives a profile of Gold(I) chemistry. This atom is not a radical.

Google is your friend.

Comment: @ Richard: You mean AuCl (Aurous Chloride) does not dissociate in to ${Au}^{+}$ and ${Cl}^{-}$.

Comment: @RajeshKSingh - AuCl probably does dissociate to some degree. However, Richard means that it is not a radical in the sense that it does not have [unpaired electrons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radical_%28chemistry%29). The electron configuration of Au(I) is $[\ce{Xe}]4f^{14} 5d^{10} $, which consists only of closed shells, i.e. no unpaired electrons.

Comment: You can definitely make gold radical cations in a mass spectrometer...